# How do I get notifyDatasetChanged() to work with a ListAdapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Right now I use setAdapter to update my ListView, but I think the proper way is to use notifiyDatasetChanged() and I can't get that to work in my main class (it's in the adapter). Here is the error:

The method notifyDatasetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter

I'm guessing there is a better way of doing this - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here's the relevant parts of my code:

```
public class ScoreList extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private ListView listViewScore;

    static List<Score> listScore = new ArrayList<Score>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.score_list);
        ctx = this;
        listScore = dbh.getAllScores();

        listViewScore = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.score_list);

        listViewScore.setAdapter(new ScoreListAdapter(ctx,
                R.layout.score_row_item, listScore));
        listViewScore.getAdapter().notifyDatasetChanged(); //this is where I get the error
    }
}
```

Here's the adapter:

```
public class ScoreListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Score> {
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ScoreListAdapter(Context ctx, int resourceId, List<Score> objects) {
        super(ctx, resourceId, objects);
        resource = resourceId;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        //context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(resource, null);

        Score score = getItem(position);

        TextView txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtName.setText(score.getName());

        TextView txtScoreChange = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.scoreChange);
        int scoreChange = Integer.parseInt(score.getScoreChange());
        if (scoreChange > 0)
            txtScoreChange.setText("+" + scoreChange);
        else if (scoreChange < 0)
            txtScoreChange.setText("" + scoreChange);
        else
            txtScoreChange.setText("");

        TextView txtScoreTotal = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.scoreTotal);
        txtScoreTotal.setText(score.getScoreTotal());

        final LinearLayout currentRow = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.scoreRowLayout);                 

        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return convertView;
    }   
}
```

Comment: It's `notifyDataSetChanged()` - notice the capital S. You have a lower-case 's' on the line you show has an error.

Comment: First of all you need to know the use of notifyDatasetChanged...Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.     Understand this before implementing... notifyDatasetChanged() will be used when the data in in your adapter data updated or simply changed..that is the collection associated with the Adapter is changed. No need to call it in the creation

Comment: Thanks, I cut out a lot of code so I wasn't calling it on creation, it just looked that way here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an instance of your custom adapter, so you can use it anywhere you like...

```
public class ScoreList extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

private ListView listViewScore;

private ScoreListAdapter adapter;

static List<Score> listScore = new ArrayList<Score>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.score_list);
    ctx = this;
    listScore = dbh.getAllScores();

    listViewScore = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.score_list);

    adapter = new ScoreListAdapter(ctx, R.layout.score_row_item, listScore);
    listViewScore.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(); 
}
}
```

By the way, if your listScore array is already loaded, then you do not need to use

```
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a very simple explanation and it works perfectly (except I had to capitalize Set in notifyDataSetChanged(); as someone else noted)

Comment: Ahh yes, i just overlooked it :) But as i said, it's not necessary to use it in your situation if your list's already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Dont call the notifyDataSetChanged(); method while creation.

only call it when content of your listViewScore changes.. and to use it at that time-

replace

```
listView.getAdapter().notifyDatasetChanged();
```

with

```
((ScoreListAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and see the magic...

thanks.